# Open page in another window (abrir pagina en otra ventana) with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code below opens `pagina.php` in the same page, but I want to open it in another window.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#select1").change(function(event){
            var id = $("#select1").find(':selected').val();
           $(location).attr('href','pagina.php?id='+id);         
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
 <body>
      <select name="select1" id="selec#1"> 
        <option value='1'>opcion una </option>
     </select>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Serais-tu assez aimable pour poser ta question en anglais ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @user2438239 Updated the answer. (He actualizado la respuesta, ver ahora).

Comment: @acdcjunior Are you a native speaker? Reckon you could translate the question also? (or people will come and delete it no doubt)

Comment: @Zenith Not really a native (I live in Brazil, many spanish-talking neighbors). I can translate the question. Should I do it? Should I also keep the spanish version in parenthesis?

Comment: @acdcjunior Yeah, in a similar style to your answer would be good. I would do it myself, but I don't really trust Google Translate to do it justice :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of (en lugar de):

```
$(location).attr('href','pagina.php?id='+id);
```

Use (utilizar):

```
window.open('pagina.php?id='+id,'_blank');
```

---

Your code corrected (el código corregido):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#select1").change(function(event){
      var id = $("#select1").find(':selected').val();
      window.open('pagina.php?id='+id,'_blank');  // changed here (cambiado aquí)
    });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <select name="select1" id="select1">     <!-- changed here (cambiado aquí) -->
      <option value='1'>opcion una</option>
      <option value='2'>opcion dos</option> <!-- changed here (cambiado aquí) -->
   </select>
 </body>
```

Comment: nice, you even added the translation xD

Comment: `id="selec#1"` should be `id="select1"` and `$("#select1").find(':selected').val();` should be `$("#select1").val()`, [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38nsd/).